# LPD8806 Arduino Uno RGB strip

Tags: arduino

To start off I'm pretty new and have never used a LED strip before. I bought a meter of RGB LEDs off of [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/160906910627?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649). The strip is based on the newer LPD8806 chip. I downloaded and tried to run the strandtest from adafruit's [library](https://github.com/adafruit/LPD8806). I can't seem to get it working correctly though. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
Strip Wiring
Black  - Ground
Green  - Pin 3 On Arduino
Red    - 5v from ATX PSU
Blue   - Pin 2 On Arduino

Arduino Uno Wiring
gnd    - Shared Ground
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: We don't know which wire is connected to which pin on the chip.

Comment: um... idk http://www.insomnialighting.com/datasheets/LPD8806.pdf

Comment: That's for the chip, not the strip itself.

Comment: Here is a close up of the strip http://imgur.com/eyTX2nr

Answer (score 1):

> **Strip Wiring**
>   Black  - Ground
>   Green  - Pin 3 On Arduino
>   Red    - 5v from ATX PSU
>   Blue   - Pin 2 On Arduino

Your connection doesn't seem to be correct, I think you are following a wrong pinout.

Based on the designators of your provided image (viewed at the right side pads which are the same as the left side pads)

[image]

The pinout is:

```
Black: Data  
Green: Clock  
Red: 5v  
Blue: Ground
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ground from the PSU connected to the ground of the arduino? If not, the strip will not work.

With a single meter of LPD 8806 you can run strandtest with the strip powered just by the arduino. I recommend getting that working before adding an external power supply.